# Find all integer numbers $n$ such that $\frac{11n-5}{n+4}$ is a perfect square.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, fractions

Find all integer numbers $n$, such that, $$\sqrt{\frac{11n-5}{n+4}}\in \mathbb{N}$$

I really tried but I couldn't guys, help please.

Comment: Could you show us what you tried? It would make it easier to pinpoint where help is needed.

Comment: see my new edit

Comment: Your new edit doesn't show any effort at all. (-1)

Comment: Oh, man I told you I tried but I got nothing

Comment: The answer to the question in your title is that $n$ runs over all natural numbers and their negatives.  Perhaps you could find a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 4):

If our square root is to be an integer, we need to have $\frac{11n-5}{n+4}$ a non-negative integer. Note that
$$\frac{11n-5}{n+4}=11-\frac{49}{n+4}.$$
So $n+4$ must divide $49$. But $49$ has very few divisors, so there are very few possile integer values of $\frac{49}{n+4}$. Try them all, including the negative ones. For each candidate, check whether the number $11-\frac{49}{n+4}$ is a perfect square.

Comment: I didn't get any thing, unfortunately

Comment: Well, one of the possible values of $\frac{49}{n+4}$ is $7$, and $11-7=4$, a perfect square. So $n+4=7$, that is, $n=3$, works.  There are $5$ other candidates, which don't work. Now we know the full answer.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $\dfrac{11n-5}{n+4} = k^2\to 11n-5=nk^2+4k^2\to n(11-k^2)=5+4k^2= 49+4(k^2-11)\to n = \dfrac{-49}{k^2-11}-4\to k^2-11 = \pm1,\pm7,\pm49.$ From this you can find all possible values of $k$, and then find $n$.